# Laravel 6 - ErrorException Undefined offset: 1. How to find exact line cause by blade file?

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-6

it cause by my blade file

```
ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1
```

in the past, Laravel 5 pointed for me what line cause the error in blade file if some thing wrong.
Now my blade file so many variable inside.
But in Laravel 6, how i can find what exact line cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

`Laravel 6` error page itself shows the line no and highlight it. For e.g Please check the below image:

[image]